# Difference between GNU grep and AIX Unix grep command options

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris, aix

What is the difference between `grep` command available on Linux (GNU grep ) and the one available on `IBM AIX` ?

> For eg: -m and -A options are not supported in IBM AIX.

This will be helpful in writing portable shell scripts. Also it would be helpful is someone can list unsupported options on Solaris too.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html

Comment: For other commands, be amazed at `http://bhami.com/rosetta.html`

Comment: Both links were useful. Thanks

Comment: Notice that you can compile GNU grep on AIX.

Answer (score 2):

N means option NOT available. It include Solaris version too.

[image: Quick reference table for grep options]